# How to create a new JSS angular app with older versions of angular/typescript

Tags: jss

I want to create a new JSS app but with older versions of angular and typescript.

I have version 11.0.2 for JSS

and when I run
`ng --version`
this is what I get

```
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.12.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.12.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.12.4
@angular-devkit/core              7.2.4
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.2.4
@angular/cli                      7.2.4
@ngtools/webpack                  7.2.4
@schematics/angular               7.2.4
@schematics/update                0.12.4
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.2.2
webpack                           4.28.4
```

If I create a new JSS app with `jss create new-app angular`, this is what my package.json looks like.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.8",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.8",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.8",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.8",
    "@angular/http": "~7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~8.2.8",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.8",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "~8.1.1",
    "@ngx-meta/core": "~7.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "~11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "~4.0.0",
    "@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss": "^14.0.1",
    "@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-angular": "^14.0.1",
    "@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-tracking": "^14.0.1",
    "apollo-angular": "~1.7.0",
    "apollo-angular-link-http-batch": "~1.7.0",
    "apollo-angular-link-persisted": "~1.1.0",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "~1.6.3",
    "apollo-client": "~2.6.4",
    "apollo-link": "~1.2.6",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "~3.2.1",
    "graphql": "14.5.8",
    "graphql-tag": "~2.10.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.3",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.8",
    "@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-angular-schematics": "^14.0.1",
    "@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli": "^14.0.1",
    "@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-dev-tools": "^14.0.1",
    "@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-manifest": "^14.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.4.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "~12.7.9",
    "body-parser": "~1.19.0",
    "chalk": "~2.4.2",
    "codelyzer": "~5.1.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "cross-env": "~6.0.2",
    "enhanced-resolve": "4.1.0",
    "express": "~4.17.1",
    "fs-extra": "~8.1.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "~2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "npm-run-all": "~4.1.5",
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "ts-loader": "~6.2.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.4.1",
    "tslint": "~5.20.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.0",
    "webpack-cli": "~3.3.9"
  }
```

It seems to create the app with all the latest versions of everything.
This is a problem as the company I work for uses node v8.10.0 so when trying to run this app it does not work.

I want to be able to create a new JSS app with the older version, any help appreciated

Juan

Answer (score 5):

`jss create` command by default pulls application template from master branch from JSS github repo (which contains the latest version). To override this behaviour you can use `jss create -b` or `jss create -s` switch:

`-b` is to select application template from specific branch from JSS github repo,

`-s` is to use local folder with JSS application template (which you can modify to have the package versions you want).

For example `jss create my-jss-app angular -b release/13.0.0` will create new JSS application from JSS 13 template.